# Splitting population data proportionally using Identity tool of ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, splitting, population, identity

I am preparing a term project and I have the vector data of the roads and zones layer for to prepare rural access index in Istanbul. My zones layer also has the attribute nufus17 which means population in the 2017 year.

I am stuck in the phase of dividing this attribute proportionally to the areas within a grid that I created via using make feature layer and identity to the zones layer. Because when I used the Identity tool areas perfectly split yet population data are not. It is just copied for each split area.

For example I had a polygon area with 1000 population now I have 2 or more polygon areas with 1000 population.

[image: 17 new Atakent area with exact same population data]

[image: original polygon just one Atakent area]

Answer (score 3):

With [Make Feature Layer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm):

> Creates a feature layer from an input feature class or layer file. The
>   layer that is created by the tool is temporary and will not persist
>   after the session ends unless the layer is saved to disk or the map
>   document is saved.

and "Use Ratio Policy" on population field:

> When Use Ratio Policy is enabled, whenever a feature in an overlay
>   operation is split, the attributes of the resulting features are a
>   ratio of the attribute value of the input feature. The output value is
>   based on the ratio in which the input feature geometry was divided.
>   For example, if the input geometry was divided equally, each new
>   feature's attribute value is assigned one-half of the value of the
>   input feature's attribute value

Population will be distributed by area.

Comment: I applied this solution and i think theoretically it should've worked.Yet, when i use ratio policy for my population data, new layer output is being created as a just empty layer. Also, after applying this tool it deletes my original data as well and returns me a drawing error.

Comment: Either you are doing something wrong or your data is broken

Comment: Can it be handled by Field Calculator? In Python Pandas it can be handled very easily by few lines of code for dividing the population per area but ArcGIS doesn't have Pandas so that makes it complex

Comment: You can calculate it using Field Calculator and/or da.UpdateCursor. If you have ArcMap >= 10.4, you have pandas. If older version you can install it to ArcMaps python Environment. I often use pandas with ArcMap.